# Metric on a tensor bundle for a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Given two tensors T and Q (0,2) on a Riemannian manifold, how I may to define their inner product? That is, what is $\langle T,S \rangle$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take an orthonormal basis of the tangent space $e_1, \ldots, e_n$. Compute $\sum_{i,j} T(e_i, e_j) S(e_i, e_j)$.

Comment: Dear Wong,  thank you! Can you show me a reference?

Answer (score 2):

Any $(0,2)$ tensor may be written (non-uniquely) as a linear combination of *indecomposable* elements, $\alpha \otimes \beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are $(0,1)$ tensors. That is
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^i \otimes \beta^i, \quad T = \sum_{j=1}^l \gamma^j \otimes \mu^j
$$
for some $l,k$. Then
$$
\tag{1}\label{eq:ip}
\langle S, T \rangle = \sum_{i,j} \langle \alpha^i, \gamma^j \rangle \langle \beta^i, \mu^j \rangle
$$
The inner product, $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$ for $(0, 1)$ tensors is defined by
$$
\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = \langle X, Y \rangle
$$
where $X, Y$ are the $(1, 0)$ tensors (i.e. vectors) obtained by musical isomorphisms of $\alpha, \beta$ respectively. That is, for any vector $Z$, $X$ is uniquely determined by
$$
\alpha(Z) = \langle X, Z \rangle
$$

Formally, to define a bilinear form on $V \otimes V$, use the [Universal Property of Tensor Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) by defining an inner product on $V \times V$ by
$$
\langle (v_1, w_1), (v_2, w_2) \rangle = \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle \langle w_1, w_2 \rangle 
$$
and then applying the universal property to obtain an inner product on $V \otimes V$. In other words, we define
$$
\langle v_1 \otimes w_1, v_2 \otimes w_2 \rangle = \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle \langle w_1, w_2 \rangle
$$
and extend by linearity to the expression given for $\langle S, T \rangle$ above in equation \eqref{eq:ip}. This is well defined by showing bilinearity in each slot and applying the universal property. The issue here is that $S$ and $T$ do not have unique expressions as sums of indecomposable elements and the universal property tells you when maps $V \times V \to W$ descend to maps $V \otimes V \to W$.

Similarly one can construct the inner product on the dual space $V^{\ast}$ from an inner product on $V$ as described above for $(0, 1)$ tensors.

Now, given a basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ for $V$, define the dual basis $\theta^i$ by
$$
\theta^i(e_j) = \delta^i_j.
$$
One can then write uniquely
$$
S = \sum_{i=1,j=1}^n S_{ij} \theta^i \otimes \theta^j, \quad T = \sum_{k=1,l=1}^n T_{kl} \theta^k \otimes \theta^l.
$$
Defining
$$
g^{ij} = \langle \theta^i, \theta^j \rangle,
$$
we have
$$
\langle \theta^i \otimes \theta^j, \theta^k \otimes \theta^l \rangle = \langle \theta^i, \theta^k \rangle \langle \theta^j, \theta^l \rangle = g^{ik} g^{jl}.
$$
Then by linearity, equation \eqref{eq:ip} becomes
$$
\langle S, T \rangle = \sum_{ijkl} \langle S_{ij} \theta^i \otimes \theta^j, T_{kl} \theta^k \times \theta^l \rangle = \sum_{ijkl} S_{ij} T_{kl} \langle \theta^i \otimes \theta^j, \theta^k \otimes \theta^l \rangle = \sum_{ijkl} S_{ij}T_{kl}g^{ik} g^{jl}
$$

In the particular case that $\{e_i\}$ is orthonormal, so that $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ we have
$$
g^{ij} = \langle \theta^i, \theta^j \rangle = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta^{ij}
$$
by the definition of the inner product on $V^{\ast}$.

Therefore,
$$
\langle S, T \rangle = \sum_{ijkl} S_{ij}T_{kl} \delta^{ik} \delta^{jl} = \sum_{ij} S_{ij}T_{ij}
$$
which is the expression give by Willie Wong in the comments since
$$
S(e_i, e_j) = (S_{kl} \theta^k \otimes \theta^l) (e_i, e_j) = S_{kl} 
\theta^k(e_i) \theta^l(e_j) = S_{kl} \delta^k_i \delta^l_j = S_{ij}
$$
and similarly for $T$.

Comment: You're welcome. The universal property uniquely determines the tensor product (up to isomorphism) so everything to do with tensor products follows from the universal property.